# Why bash ignored the quotation in ls output?

Tags: bash

Below is a script and its output describing the problem I found today. Even though `ls` output is quoted, `bash` still breaks at the whitespaces. I changed to use `for file in *.txt`, just want to know why `bash` behaves this way.

```
[chau@archlinux example]$ cat a.sh 
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(ls --quote-name *.txt)
echo "Value of \$FILES:"
echo $FILES
echo

echo "Loop output:"
for file in $FILES
do
    echo $file
done
[chau@archlinux example]$ ./a.sh 
Value of $FILES:
"b.txt" "File with space in name.txt"

Loop output:
"b.txt"
"File
with
space
in
name.txt"
```

Comment: ls is returning a string, and the loop is breaking on delimiters, so spaces, new lines etc.  Usually for this kinda think I usually do:  `for i in $(ls *.txt); do echo $i; done` and then you can just pass `$i` into whatever you need one.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why it doesn't work. However, your suggest doesn't work for me, file name with spaces will be broken into multiple names. I use `for i in *.txt`, it is shorter and works correctly.

Comment: @DDMC The key issue is that, once a shell-active character —like a quote— is inside a string, it is no longer treated as shell-active.  It becomes a character like any other.  This is useful and important for security but it does surprise people who are new to shell.   For more information, see, for example: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: There is a [section](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) in Greg's Bash Pitfalls that discusses some of the issues with commands like `f in $(ls *.txt)`.  Further, if you have an interest in shell, I recommend looking through all of Greg's excellent collection of [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: See why [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) says never use `for i in $(ls anything)` -- which is what you are essentially doing using an intermediate variable to hold the `ls --quote-name *.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why bash ignored the quotation in ls output?

Because word splitting happens on the result of variable expansion.

When evaluating a statement the shell goes through different phases, called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions). One of these phases is ["word splitting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting). Word splitting literally does split your variables into separate words, quoting from the bash manual:

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.
>
> The shell treats each character of $IFS as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators. . If IFS is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words. ...

When shell has a `$FILES`, that is not within double quotes, it firsts does "parameter expansion". It expands `$FILES` to the string `"b.txt" "File with space in name.txt"`. Then word splitting occurs. So with the default `IFS`, the resulting string is split/separated on spaces, tabs or newlines.

To prevent word splitting the `$FILES` has to be inside double quotes itself, no the value of `$FILES`.

Well, you could do this (unsafe):

```
ls -1 --quote-name *.txt |
while IFS= read -r file; do
  eval file="$file"
  ls -l "$file"
done
```

- tell ls to output newline separated list `-1`
- read the list line by line
- re-evaulate the variable to remove the quotes with `evil`. I mean `eval`
- I use `ls -l "$file"` inside the loop to check if `"$file"` is a valid filename.

This will still not work on all filenames, because of `ls`. Filenames with unreadable characters are just ignored by my `ls`, like `touch "c.txt"$'\x01'`. And filenames with embedded newlines will have problems like `ls $'\n'"c.txt"`.

That's why it's advisable to forget `ls` in scripts - `ls` is only for nice-pretty-printing in your terminal. In scripts use `find`.

If your filenames have no newlines embedded in them, you can:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    ls -l "$file"
done
```

If your filenames are just anything, use a null-terminated stream:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d'' file; do
    ls -l "$file"
done
```

Many, many unix utilities (`grep -z`, `xargs -0`, `cut -z`, `sort -z`) come with support for handling zero-terminated strings/streams just for handling all the strange filenames you can have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follwing snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r file; do
    echo "$file"
done < <(ls --quote-name *.txt)
```

Comment: What is the point of that? There's nothing useful you can do with `$file`.